# Change language to pt-br [ngx-boostrap]

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

How i can change de langiage os BSdatePicker to pt_br
I tried to modify in bs-locale-service so i have this mensage of error Khronos locale error: please load locale "pt-br" before using it

Answer (score 5):

First step is to add locale to Chronos

```
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { ptBrLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('pt-br', ptBrLocale);
```

Second step, say datepicker to use this locale:

```
 constructor(private localeService: BsLocaleService) {
   localeService.use('pt-br');
 }
```

Comment: It's also well documented on the website: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales

Comment: @hgoebl I wouldn't call it "well documented". Search around and you'll find people referencing the documentation but unable to understand "Where" to add the code to get it to work.

Comment: It&#39;s open source, you are always welcome to do something useful, like PR with documentation improvement or reporting issues, answering questions on stack overflow, etc.