# Production Angular 7 app produces runtime errors in console related to ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap, angular7

I have an Angular 7 app that's been happily using `ngx-bootstrap`. Now that I've tried to publish the app after a while, I am getting the errors below. If I just use the app in development mode, all is well. I am using Visual Studio for development and publishing but I can reproduce this just using the CLI. Apparently, `ng serve` works just fine while `ng serve --prod` gives me the errors below (stripped for clarity). This is all related to `bsDaterangepicker`.

```
Khronos locale error: please load locale "en" before using it
(anonymous) @ main.f09bc86ef36b4bf3b010.js:1
main.f09bc86ef36b4bf3b010.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Locale "en" is not defined, please add it with "defineLocale(...)"
Error: Locale "en" is not defined, please add it with "defineLocale(...)"
    at e.writeValue (main.f09bc86ef36b4bf3b010.js:1)
main.f09bc86ef36b4bf3b010.js:1 Khronos locale error: please load locale "en" before using it
```

I have found [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260815/change-language-to-pt-br-ngx-boostrap) that I thought could help me workaround the problem but that did not work.

I have tried going back a few revisions of my `package.json` but that didn't seem to help. It seems as if Angular production build optimizations are making a mess. And just as I was getting ready to post the question, I tried `ng serve --prod --optimization=false` which seems to fix the issue. But apparently, that's not ideal. Is this something one can hope will be fixed in the upcoming Angular versions?

Comment: Check this link, if it helps you: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4054

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already. I used `defineLocale` to actually define the missing `en` locale but got some very weird behavior.

Comment: // The string MUST be lower case - even though the examples give it as enGb
defineLocale('engb', enGbLocale); (taken from answer in above link). If it doesn't work, a sample would be great as several developers can run and identify problem.

Comment: Well, if you look carefully the error complains about "en" locale. So if I just use "en" I get some strange behavior. Doesn't work properly. Other than this, feels like an Angular issue rather than `ngx-bootstrap`... I am working on a simple project that is able to reproduce this.

Comment: Okay, so I have a project that reproduces the issue. How could I share it? It appears as if ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 does not have this problem but this still appears to be Angular optimization issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't work in production: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hs3dwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like a bug (so there is no real solution to it), and it has been reported here:

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4752

<s>possible workarounds until it is solved:</s>

- downgrade to ngx-bootstrap 3.0.1
- compile by setting `buildOptimizer` to false

**EDIT**: the issue has been solved, so the solution is simply update your ngx-bootstrap to the latest version available

Comment: I've done both. Prefer the first one though. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: for me it was enough to downgrade to `ngx-bootstrap 3.0.1`. There was no need to downgrade the Angular version too.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ngx-bootstrap do you use?
If 3.1.1 try disable "buildOptimizer": false

Comment: Yes, 3.1.1 but if you look at my question closely I already asserted that it's working w/o build optimizations. But that's not acceptable. After today's Angular minor upgrade, I have to keep both ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 and @angular/language-service@7.0.1 in order for things to work. If I upgrade any or both, the production build breaks.

Comment: @wpfwannabe you start by saying "Yes, 3.1.1" but later in the comment you reference version 3.0.1. Which one are you using and did you get this resolved?